# Quantizing a TensorFlow graph for inference

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I'm trying to quantize my model (a CNN) in order to convert it to a quantized .tflite model. 
I'm following the tutorial at: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.13/tensorflow/contrib/quantize#quantization-aware-training

First of all, I introduce fake quantization nodes in my graph by calling:

```
tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph(quant_delay=500)
```

but then, when at the end I try to to call this function to make sure that the graph is exported with the quantization information in the right format:

```
tf.contrib.quantize.create_eval_graph(input_graph=tf.get_default_graph())
```

I get this error:

**`ValueError: Training op found in graph, exiting {'ApplyAdam'}`**

and indeed, when building the graph, I effectively added an AdamOptimizer to train my model:

```
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(...)
```

How to solve that problem? The error seems to suggest that I should remove the Adam optimizer, although I need it for training.

I couldn't find any help about this on TensorFlow web pages and tutorials nor in other forums. I hope you can help me out

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be a bit involved but you need to create two separate and distinct graphs, one for training and one for exporting. Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/crypt3lx2k/cec6ad66b948fe0e77a7b1e6d2205bf4) for an example of training, then finetuning with quantization aware training, exporting and conversion.

Step 1)

In the training graph you create everything up to loss normally, then call `tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph(...)` before adding your `train_op` with the optimizer. Train your model then make a checkpoint, you can do this through the `tf.estimator` API or just regularly in a `tf.Session`.

---

Step 2)

Then you need to create an inference graph, you don't even make the loss function here just the inference part of your model. After that call `tf.contrib.quantize.create_eval_graph(...)` to add the quantization ops. 
Finally you just restore from the checkpoint created in training and then you export to your desired format either frozengraph or savedmodel.

---

Step 3)

Convert the frozengraph/savedmodel to tflite using toco.

Comment: Amazing, it worked! Thank you so much. 
By the way, I have another concern. Because I was trying to quantize a toy model that I can easily train from scratch in a few seconds (just a couple convolution layers and fully-connected layers), I actually skipped the "fine-tuning" part. But if I had a pre-trained model in .pb format, would I be able to quantize it using quantization-aware training without retraining it from scratch or compromising its accuracy? Because I mean, in order to get quantization information you need to feed some training data to the model anyway, so how to do that?

Comment: If all you have is a frozengraph I suppose it would be possible to load it then manipulate it inline but I've never tried it. What you would have to do is to check out which ops the `tf.contrib.quantize` functions actually add and then try to emulate it. I estimate that would be a lot of work.

Comment: If you have the code to build the graph it's much simpler to build it again from scratch with the `create_*_graph` functions in the correct places then simply warm-start the variables from the existing checkpoint. If you look in the gist, the first `train.py` script doesn't actually add anything to do with quantization. So that first checkpoint only has regular trained weights with no quantization info added.

Comment: Hi there, so now tf upgraded to v2 and they deleted contrib which means quantize is gone, please i want to ask, what are the current alternatives for those two quantize functions: `create_training_graph` and `create_eval_graph`. Thank you